# Error: read ECONNRESET with Mysql and Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have my backend application developed with nestjs and typeorm. I use a mysql database. Hosting is on Heroku. When Heroku used Mysql 5.6 everything was fine, but now it was updated to Mysql 8, I started receiving errors like Error: read ECONNRESET in the different queries. It seems kind of random, since you do it in different queries. Heroku support only says that it may be momentary network errors, but I have been having this problem for 2 weeks. Some help?

This is what Heroku support wrote:

```
Purchase a New ClearDB Add-on:
    Visit the Heroku Dashboard.
    Navigate to your application.
    Access the Resources tab.
    Under Add-ons, search for and add the ClearDB MySQL add-on.
    Choose the appropriate plan based on your database needs.

Backup Your Data:
    Before making any changes, ensure that you have a recent backup of your MySQL 5.6 database.

Migrate Your Data:
    Use the backup to migrate your data from MySQL 5.6 to MySQL 8.
    You can follow the ClearDB documentation or reach out to our support team for assistance.
```

This is the error shown in the consolelog:

```
2024-03-11T12:17:30.136457+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Error: read ECONNRESET
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138441+00:00 app[web.1]: [31m[Nest] 21  - [39m
03/11/2024, 9:17:30 AM [31m  ERROR[39m [38;5;3m[ExceptionsHandler] [39m[31mread ECONNRESET[39m

2024-03-11T12:17:30.138483+00:00 app[web.1]: QueryFailedError: read ECONNRESET

2024-03-11T12:17:30.138483+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.onResult (/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:165:37)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138484+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection._notifyError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:228:21)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138484+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection._handleFatalError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:183:10)

2024-03-11T12:17:30.138484+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PoolConnection._handleNetworkError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:196:10)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138485+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138485+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138486+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
2024-03-11T12:17:30.138486+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Comment: please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html  you must first upgradde to 5.7 and then to 8

Comment: The issue is that Heroku made the update, it was not up to me.

Comment: can you please add all images as text

Comment: Ready, it would be

Comment: as isaid before the way to 8 goes over 5,7, restore your old database and follow the steps on the mysql site#

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. Heroku only supports Mysql 8 now.

Comment: then take the backup install mysql 5.6 on your local machine or vm and install the backup and the convert it to 5.7 and then  8.0

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do that, my only backup is the current one in Mysql 8. I'm surprised that Heroku has caused this problem...

Comment: that doesn't matter, use that and fix eventual happening error, which i don't beleive, and next time make backups regurlarly

Comment: Heroku didn't do this: they don't have a MySQL offering, so they have nothing to upgrade. If you're using an addon to get MySQL support, reach out to the company that provides the addon.

Comment: Yes, it is actually the ClearDB MySQL Database plugin, which works within Heroku. I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: I am using HeidiSql as a database manager. Download the Heroku database (Mysql 8). Locally install Mysql 5.6, import the database and export it. Install Mysql 5.7 locally, import the database and export it. Go to Heroku and finally import it. I keep getting the same error. In addition, I canceled the clearDB service and acquired JawsDB. It keeps giving the error randomly. Any help please?